# JQuery: Wrong form data encoding in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying execute this simple AJAX request with JQuery:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("foo", "bar");
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/example",
    type: "post",
    data: data,
    processData: false
});
```

I check request by Google Chrome developer tools. I see that Content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` which is expected, but actual data sent in multipart encoding:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryEzaaFpNlUo3QpKe1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name: "foo"

bar
------WebKitFormBoundaryEzaaFpNlUo3QpKe1--
```

Of course my backend application doesn't expect such encoding and fails. What is wrong and how to force JQuery to send data in urlencoded format? I tried pass extra headers or contentType options, but nothing works.

Comment: Use the `serialize()` function of jQuery instead of `FormData`

Comment: Are you sure your backend can't handle `multipart/form-data`? Try adding `contentType: false`.

Answer (score 1):

u should also add  `contentType: false`

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/example",
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {

         }
    });
```

Comment: Why should you add this? Can you explain your contribution?

Answer (score 0):

`FormData` is always sent as `multipart/form-data`. It's usually used when you're uploading a file or blob, which can't be URL-encoded.

If you want URL-encoded, don't use `FormData`. Use a regular object, and jQuery will encode it properly.

```
const data = {foo: "bar"};
```

Also, don't use `processData: false` when you're doing this.